# How do I wrap two render array elements in a div?

Tags: 7, theming

Given this renderable array:

```
$output = array(
    'twitter-icon' => array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div class="twitter-icon"></div>'
    ),
    'twitter-link' => array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => l('follow us on Twitter', 'https://twitter.com/#!/zujava'),
    ), 
  );
```

How do I wrap both of these elements in a single DIV?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can also use the `#container` form element, and code similar to the following one:

```
$wrapper = array(
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('class-name'),
  ),
);

$wrapper['twitter-icon'] => array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => '<div class="twitter-icon"></div>'
);

$wrapper['twitter-link'] => array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => l(t('follow us on Twitter'), 'https://twitter.com/#!/zujava'),
);
```

The [#container](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#container) element wraps its children elements with a `<div>` tag, whose CSS class is the one passed in the `#attributes` property.

You could even use a container for the "twitter-icon" element, but that doesn't give you any pro, except in the case you could possibly add an element to that, as with the following code:

```
$wrapper = array(
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('class-name'),
  ),
);

$wrapper['twitter-icon'] => array(
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('twitter-icon'),
  ),
);

if ($condition) {
  $wrapper['twitter-icon']['twitter-icon-text'] => array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => t('Icon text'),
  );
}

$wrapper['twitter-link'] => array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => l(t('follow us on Twitter'), 'https://twitter.com/#!/zujava'),
);
```

Comment: To me this is the best answer, as it uses the physical array structure to represent what is being wrapped, will copy and paste better (moving an element in @ninjascorner answer could break the opening/closing DIVs), and doesn't require extra theme functions. Thanks!

Comment: That is correct: You can add another element that is rendered in the same container, without moving the `#suffix` property from the last element, or the `#prefix` property from the first element, to the new added element. As you said, this is less error-prone.

Answer (score 7):

Is this what are you looking for?

```
$output = array(
    'twitter-icon' => array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div class="twitter-icon"></div>'
      '#prefix' => '<div class="test">',
    ),
    'twitter-link' => array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => l('follow us on Twitter', 'https://twitter.com/#!/fdgf'),
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ), 
);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @nija  +1ed,  Great answer I had forgotten those attributes.    Please read my answer, can this be achieved through theming based alternative to your suffix and prefix.

Comment: @stefgosselin, you mean you want to create a tpl file to theme it?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I knew how to do this on one element, but it didn't occur to me split up the suffix and prefix. Interesting. It feels messy to me, but I can't articulate why so I can't really have an issue.

Comment: @ninjascorner Sorry for the delay, I could not find the note I had on this subject. There is also I think a way possible less elegant than other answers,  usable in theme or module that is  using the theme hook `theme_render_example_add_div`      

See http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/render_example--render_example.module/function/theme_render_example_add_div/7)

Comment: This is only good if you're super sure that both elements will always get rendered. It is easy to end up with unclosed <div> when splitting like this.

Answer (score 2):

You also can create a theme for this.

```
$form['twitter']['#theme'] = 'my_twitter_theme';

$form['twitter']['icon'] = array(
'twitter-icon' => array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => '<div class="twitter-icon"></div>'
);

$form['twitter']['link'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => l('follow us on Twitter', 'https://twitter.com/#!/zujava'),
);
```

And in your theme hook:

```
function my_hook_theme(){
  return array(
    'my_twitter_theme' => array('form' => NULL)
  );
}
```

And in the theme function:

```
function theme_my_twitter_theme($form){
  $output = "";

  $output .= "<div class=\"twitter\">";
  $output .= drupal_render($form['icon']);
  $output .= drupal_render($form['link']);
  $output .= "</div>";    

  $output .= drupal_render($form);
  return $output;
}
```

*I use this in Drupal 6, i'm not sure if works also in D7 but i hope so*

Comment: Yes, I figured this method out after posting (well, I copies the examples module). It works great, but I don't consider it the best method because (if I understand correctly), you have to put your class name in the function, reduces it's reusability.